# How do i slice a given data to another table form in Python? without using SQL libraries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filtering, numpy-slicing

i begun to learn python for data science, but after sql i started to fail slicing with python.

So my data is:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and i needed it to look like this;

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How can i do this with python without using SQL libraries.

Comment: Please do not use `sql` tag and enact rule of engagement *python without using SQL libraries.* at the same time.

Comment: yea this should do, any help ??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a very broad question but I would suggest to look into using pandas framework. Look it up find some tutorials. It will make everything easy(as easy as data science can be anyway).

Answer (score 0):

using a pandas dataframe
you could them merge them
Typically the Avg_Bill_Amount would be the result of a groupby like so:

```
df.groupby(['Customer_number']).mean()
```

For the last date I would try:

```
df.groupby(['Customer_number'], sort=False)['service_bill_amount'].max()
```

then you would have to merge them together on the customer number

Answer (score 0):

You can use "pandas" library. Convert it into a dataframe and use `groupby()` function.

Let's say you have a dataframe `data` containing first table from your question.

First of all, you have to [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) unnecessary columns.

```
data.drop(['Service_Bill_Date'], inplace=True)
```

Now with [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
data.groupby(by=['CustomerNo']).mean()
```

Comment: So, this is a broad question. You have to perform some steps in order to achieve the result you wanted. I am assuming you need to group the table by CustomerNo. as your example result has two rows. First, you would need to get the average amount by dropping the date. Then process the dates and merge both data frames.